# Is it possible to use unused space on floated elements?

Tags: list, css-float, space

I got a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9BCwL/2/

It's about an unsorted list displayed in two columns. To arrange the elements the attribute "float: left;" is used. In my example you can see, that the second item got a line break, if it is too long. The third item is positioned on the left side, that's correct. But because of the line break in the second element, there is a gab between the third and first element. Is it possible to use that space (to move the third element up) using CSS? Maybe there is an CSS attribute I don't know. Thanks in advance! :)

Greetz
Sy

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="my-list">
     <ul>
         <li><span>Element 1</span></li>
         <li><span>This is an extra loooooooong, looooooong Element 2</span></li>
         <li><span>Element 3</span></li>
         <li><span>Element 4</span></li>
         <li><span>Element 5</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-list {
    width: 550px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.my-list ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 0 0 14px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}
    .my-list ul li {
        float: left;
        padding: 0 0 5px;
        line-height: 20px;
        list-style: none;
        width: 240px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for that plugin write in jquery example this one [jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) this is what you looking for. I'm not sure, but pure css is not sufficient for that.

Comment: Thx for the hint. But masonry is a little too much for that little problem. I thought maybe that would be possible by changing the style in some way. ;)